# woocommerce buyers emails on frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i have created Website using [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org) and [WooCommerce](http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) Plugin, and i have success making users post products from frontend, 
i want to display product orders

as you can see in this image
[image: detailed images]

i success showing total sales for the product, 
now i want to show all buyers infomations for the product/

so far i have got this code

```
<?php

 $p = $post->ID;
 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'shop_order',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
   'posts_per_page' => '-1'
 );

 $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
 $customer_orders = $my_query->posts;
 //print_r($customer_orders);
 foreach ($customer_orders as $customer_order) {
   $order = new WC_Order();
   $order->populate($customer_order);
   $orderdata = (array) $order;
   $fields = array_values($orderdata);
   //print_r($fields);
   echo 'Status: '.$fields[1];                           
   echo '<br>Date  : '.$fields[2];                           
   echo '<br>Email  : '.$fields[16];                           

 }

?>
```

This Code is Working Fine But it Show details about all products

**What i Want is:** to show informations about about product depending on product ID

so i want to edit this code to get results depending on `post->id`

```
$p = $post->ID;
     $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'shop_order',
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
       'posts_per_page' => '-1'
     );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so reading your question and assuming $post->ID is the id of the product you want to display the orders containing, this is what you need:

```
<?php
$products = array();
foreach (get_posts('post_type=shop_order&numberposts=-1&post_status=publish') as $order) {
    $order = new WC_Order($order->ID);
    foreach($order->get_items('line_item') as $item) {
        $product_id = (!empty($item['variation_id'])) ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id'];
        $products[] = $product_id;
    }
    if (in_array($post->ID,$products)) {
        echo 'Status: '.$order->order_status;                         
        echo '<br>Date  : '.$order->order_date;                           
        echo '<br>Email  : '.$order->billing_email; 
    }   
}
```

Comment: and the `WC_Order` is only take order Id NOT `$post->ID`

Comment: Sorry, I read the comments to the first answer and thought it was doing what you needed, if it was mine would be a simpler code to do the same thing. I have just reread your question I will redo my code

Comment: Thank You, Waiting You Code

Comment: It didn't show any results, even if i make this code like this
`$products = array($post->ID);` it will show all orders for all products, I want Only to show orders for the product NOT all orders.
@Liam

Comment: Sorry I made mistake in the code - line-item instead of line_item I have corrected it now

Comment: That's Works Very Fine and Perfect BUT when i created another user and make a product and buy it, it suppose to show me who bought this item BUT it show me all orders Please Take a look here at [This Image A](http://awesomescreenshot.com/09926on3f3) And [This Image B](http://awesomescreenshot.com/08526onp3d)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question well, maybe you can try this. But you have to make sure that `$post` is refering to the order.

```
$p = $post->ID;

$args = array(
    'p' => $p,
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1'
);

$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    $my_query->next_post();
    $customer_order = $my_query->post;      

    $order = new WC_Order();
    $order->populate($customer_order);
    $orderdata = (array) $order;
    $fields = array_values($orderdata);
    //print_r($fields);
    echo 'Status: '.$fields[1];                           
    echo '<br>Date  : '.$fields[2];                           
    echo '<br>Email  : '.$fields[16];       
}
```

You can read the doc of the WP_Query() function here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

Comment: of your answer yes u did understand my question i have Try this solution before and it didn't work @guillaume

Comment: @YoussefSubehi Can you check my edit ? You have only one product to display ?

Comment: @YoussefSubehi if it still does not work, please describe the error precisely.

Comment: there is no error shown it's just don't show anything 
in this video im showing you that, Please Take a Look Here [This Video](http://screenr.com/DWTN)
@Guillaume Royer

Comment: OK I understand ! The `$p = $post->ID;` is the ID of the *product*, which is distinct from the *order* ! So there is if course no post with this ID and of type 'shop_order'. Don't you have any way to get the *order* ID ? (In short to set $post to the *order* and not the *product* on the first line.)

Comment: BUT as you can see in the video it shows all the orders for all products what i want is to show the orders Only for the product who have id 39 for example

Comment: also in the video i showed u even if i enter the id directly without `$p = $post->ID;` it didn't show anything also

Comment: Yes, because you enter the ID of the product. Product and orders are conceptually different. Orders have their own IDs. Either you find the orders by looking in the doc if there is function for getting one product's all orders, either you lookup in the database for orders, but you have to find the field in order data which contains product's ID (if there is such a field).

But it is obviously not the main ID field, which is the order's ID itself, different from product's ID you get on the first line.

Comment: so what should i do ? step by step please.