# Woocommerce WC_Order -> populate(), unrecogonized characters in keys

Tags: php, wordpress, utf-8, woocommerce

I ran this code to read orders from a Woocommerce store:

[Woocommerce - php to get order information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198307/woocommerce-php-to-get-order-information#18224662)

It works great, but this line returns an array with unrecogonized characters in it's key:

```
foreach ($customer_orders as $customer_order) {
 $order = new WC_Order();

 $order->populate($customer_order);
```

provides an array with this key:

```
□*□data
```

I would like to access this key in my code, but I can't read what those unrecognized characters are.

I ran it through UTF-8 htmlentities, but no luck.

I have workarounds, but it's easier if I can write out that key.

Comment: Do you have the order ID? Why not just use `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id )`?

Comment: yes, I'll probably just do that.